# How to tweak the MongoDB query to get the output in descending order

Tags: mongodb-query

I am working with a OSM file converted to JSON.In this query, I am trying to  fetch the count of all the amenities in the .json file.I need to know how to get the output reverse.

Query :-

```
db.char.aggregate([{"$match":{"amenity":{"$exists":1}}}, {"$group":{"_id":"$amenity",
"count":{"$sum":1}}}, {"$sort":{"count":­1}}, {"$limit":100}])
```

Current Output:-

```
{ "_id" : "bar", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "fitness_center", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "fountain", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "studio", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "telephone", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "nightclub", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "shelter", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "courthouse", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "kindergarten", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "doctors", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "laboratory", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "toilets", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "community_centre", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "embassy", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "fire_station", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "townhall", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "prison", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "clinic", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "pub", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "grave_yard", "count" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**{"$sort":{"count":-1}}**

in the sort part should do you!